# How can I get data from multiple database in asp.net webapi mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, join, asp.net-web-api

I try to get data from multiple database but I get the following error

> System.NotSupportedException: 'The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts.

Code:

```
private EmployeesEntities db = new EmployeesEntities();
private LogEntities Logdb = new LogEntities();

// GET: api/employees
public IHttpActionResult GetEmployees()
{
    var query = (from emp in db.employees /*where ToInt32(emp.active) =1*/
                 join location in db.locations on emp.location_id equals location.id
                 into emp_loc
                 from location in emp_loc.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 where emp.active.Equals(1)

                 join position in Logdb.positions on emp.employee_number equals position.employee_number

                 select new
                        {
                             emp.employee_number,
                             emp.employee_photo,
                             emp.first_name,
                             emp.last_name,
                             position.position1
                        });
 
    var employees = query.ToList();
 
    return Ok(employees);
}
```

Comment: You can't query from 2 different contexts. One thing you could do, is grab your `positions` into a `List` and query against that. There are other options as well such as referencing your log table via a database view.

Comment: @SteveGreene I am a newbie how can I implement that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
var employees = db.employees.Where(e => e.active.Equals(1)).ToList();
var positions = Logdb.positions.ToList();

var results = (from emp in employees 
               join pos in positionss on emp.employee_number equals pos.employee_number
               select new 
               {
                     emp.employee_number,
                     emp.employee_photo,
                     emp.first_name,
                     emp.last_name,
                     pos.position1
               });

        return Ok(results.ToList());
```

If you are dealing with a lot of data I would do it in a stored procedure or setup a database view.